Broken spacing before calligraphic letters in math
I am using Tom de Jong’s thesis template, which configures fonts as follows (in packages.sty):
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[final]{microtype}

\usepackage[ttscale=.75]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

% Set nicer (= less bold, less vertical spacing) mathcal font
\usepackage[cal=cm]{mathalpha}

Setting the cal=cm option when loading mathalpha replaces the calligraphic letters of newtxmath with those of the cm typeface. These look much more natural than the calligraphic letters of newtxmath.
Unfortunately, however, this results in weird spacing when a math expression starts with a calligraphic letter. The problem is more prominent when the text is in italic style. Here is an example:

After the words distributive and with above, the spaces before the mathematical expressions are noticeably smaller.
What is the exact cause of this problem and what is the best way to fix it?

it would help if you provided a small complete document that showed the problem, preferably as a single file, with the needed declarations in the preamble and an example text showing bad spacing

The Linux Libertine font is quite tight with interword spacing and the \mathcal letters have no sidebearings.
You might add some space yourself, but it requires a syntax change.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[final]{microtype}

\usepackage[ttscale=.75]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

% Set nicer (= less bold, less vertical spacing) mathcal font
\usepackage[cal=cm]{mathalpha}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\NewDocumentCommand{\prefix}{m}{%
  \ifhmode
    \ifdim\lastskip>0pt
      \unskip
      \begingroup
      \xspaceskip=1.25\fontdimen2\font
      \spacefactor2000\relax
      \space
      \endgroup
    \fi
  \fi
  $\mathcal{#1}$\nobreakdash-%
}

\begin{document}

For every distributive \prefix{U}lattice $L$ and \prefix{V}lattice

For every distributive $\mathcal{U}$\nobreakdash-lattice $L$,

\prefix{U}lattices are important

\begin{lemma}
For every distributive\/ \prefix{U}lattice $L$, 
the orders
\begin{align*}
x \le_{1} y &\equiv (x \wedge y) =_{L} x \\
x \le_{2} y &\equiv (x \vee y) =_{L} y
\end{align*}
form partial orders \prefix{U}small truth
values and are equivalent to each other.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}


